# Problems with apt-get(unmet dependencies)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 12.04(64 bit). 
I have downloaded skype from the official website and opened the deb package from the terminal(`sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb`) but install did not finish successfully. 
Now whatever I try to install I get the following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Conflicts: skype-bin
              Conflicts: skype-bin:i386 but 4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
 skype-bin:i386 : Breaks: skype:i386 (< 4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 4.1.0.20-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Of course I tried running apt-get -f install, but when I do, I get the following output:

```
...
After this operation, 36.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libssl1.0.0.
 skype-bin:i386 (4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) breaks skype (<< 4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) and is installed.
  Version of skype:i386 to be configured is 4.1.0.20-1.
dpkg: error processing skype:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

You can also have a look at the output from `dpkg --list` [here.](http://pastebin.com/XqWK0AYH)

I have also tried running `sudo apt-get remove skype-bin`, but again it fails with similar error.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching round the internet, I have finally found a solution for my problem. I directly used `dpkg` to remove `skype:i386`. In a terminal type:

```
sudo dpkg -r skype:i386
```

Hope this will save the day I wasted on this for someone.

Comment: +1 for finding your answer and thanks for posting back. Please accept your answer to make it clear that this is the solution (and get a little rep).

Comment: I can accept my own answer tomorrow(according to the message box). As the initial part of your comment -this is [the wisdom of the ancients](http://xkcd.com/979) :)

Comment: Ahh, xkcd... :)

Comment: thanks a lot!! i wasted my 3 hours looking for this!! works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

This two commands worked for me. There is no harm in doing this

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo dpkg -r skype:i386`